# I get lines on the 4 edges of every page when I compile a template? How do I remove these?

Tags: pdf, compiling, texstudio, cropmarks

I'm not sure why, but I get the following lines on each of the 4 edges of every page, how can I remove these? Other people that compile the same template on their system, do not get these lines.

[image]

Comment: Without see a code of small complete document, which reproduce this edges, is hard to say anything. Probably they are crop marks, which you require in your document.

Comment: @Zarko But I don't think its in the template code, because other people that are compiling the same template don't get these linse?

Comment: Than you have such settings in your editor. I0m not familiar with  `textstudio` , so at this I can't help you.

Comment: We at least need to see the template and which options you are giving the template. It is clearly cropmarks and the editor is unlikely to add these, it comes from the latex run.