# by using \ref it shows the full label as well as the caption, while i only want to have the numbering

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

The minimal working code =

```
\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
%
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
    breaklinks=true,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue,
    linkcolor=black,
    menucolor=blue,
    anchorcolor=red,
    pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1},
    bookmarksnumbered=false,
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=0}
%
\begin{document}
    For a full understanding of the air intake system relevant to the problem Figure \ref{fig:1.1} will be used as an example
    %
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=40mm,height=50mm]{system outline.PNG}
        \caption{simplified block diagram air intake system}
        \label{fig:1.1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But then the result is like shown in the picture below:
[image]

However i only want the numbers to be shown, if the phrasing of my question is wrong please excuse me for that.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use `\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}`?

Comment: by not using that in the minimal working example it indeed solves the problem however when i run my full file it shows the following error:
Extra \endgroup. \begin{document}
and a way to solve this is by using the older latex version.

Comment: rollback with latexrelease works as well as it can but can only provide short term fixes, there is absolutely no guarantee  a format rolled back to 2020 will work with any packages updated in a 2022 texlive

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution: [Cross reference not working as intended, the entire name of reference and label gets printed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667938/cross-reference-not-working-as-intended-the-entire-name-of-reference-and-label) by Ulrike Fischer

You just need to add the following code:

```
\makeatletter
 \DeclareRobustCommand\ref{%
    \@ifstar\@refstar\T@ref
  }%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\pageref{%
    \@ifstar\@pagerefstar\T@pageref
  }%
 \makeatother
```

Full code:

```
\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
 \DeclareRobustCommand\ref{%
    \@ifstar\@refstar\T@ref
  }%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\pageref{%
    \@ifstar\@pagerefstar\T@pageref
  }%
 \makeatother

%
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
    breaklinks=true,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue,
    linkcolor=black,
    menucolor=blue,
    anchorcolor=red,
    pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1},
    bookmarksnumbered=false,
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=0}
%
\begin{document}
    For a full understanding of the air intake system relevant to the problem Figure \ref{fig:1.1} will be used as an example
    %
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=40mm,height=50mm]{system outline.PNG}
        \caption{simplified block diagram air intake system}
        \label{fig:1.1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That solved it, thanks very much! i was really struggling