# Broken table of content with pdfscreen

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfscreen

I write a presentation using pdfscreen, with an old version `\RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease}`. When I try to make table of content, the names of the sections are broken, displaying `.1. *` as a title, and all the section and subsection are formated with `0.x`. Plus, the 3 first section/part are skipped (see image below).

[image]

The whole code :

```
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
\RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, latexsym, stmaryrd, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx, helvet}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{color, url}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{proof}

% Couleurs
\definecolor{boeuf}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.15}
\definecolor{brun}{rgb}{0.4,0.1,0.2}
\definecolor{bouteille}{rgb}{0.02,0.3,0.3}
\definecolor{marine}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.7}

% Configuration de pdfscreen
\usepackage[screen, sectionbreak, orange]{pdfscreen}
\margins{1.6in}{.7in}{.6in}{.6in}
\screensize{5in}{6.7in}
\overlay{fonds/bonbons}

% Commandes personnalisées
\newcommand{\blu}[1]{\textcolor{marine}{\bf #1}}

\newcommand{\forces}{\Vdash}
\newcommand{\existe}{\exists}
\newcommand{\pourtout}{\forall}
\newcommand{\implique}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\et}{\land}
\newcommand{\ou}{\lor}

\newcommand{\saut}{\vfill}
\newcommand{\carre}{\square}
\newcommand{\losange}{\Diamond}

% Configuration du titre et des auteurs
\title{{\large \bf \qquad Blabla logic, Elevator \\
\blu{Referent : xxxxx XXXXXX}}}

\author{
\small\color{boeuf} John DOE\\   
\small\color{boeuf} Janne DOES\\
\footnotesize Due 25 may 2023\\}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\date{}

\renewcommand\part[1]{%
    \clearpage
    \vspace*{5em}
    \Large 
    \begin{center}\stepcounter{part}\textcolor{marine}{\bf \Alph{part}\quad #1 }\end{center}
    \vspace*{5em}
    \large 
    \clearpage
}

\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\newcounter{sec}[part]
\setcounter{sec}{0}

\renewcommand\section[1]{
    \clearpage
    \par\bigskip 
    \stepcounter{sec}
    \textcolor{bouteille}{\Large \bf \Alph{part}.\arabic{sec}.\quad #1}\newline\par
} 

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus1fill}


\begin{document} 

\large 
\maketitle

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\pagebreak 

\newpage
\part{Introduction}

\section{Présentation} 


\section{Modal Logic} 

\subsection{Box et losange}

...

\end{document}
```

I've searched across stackexchange and Google, but I didn't find anything relevant. I have absolutely no idea from where the bug comes from.
Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: it won't work. hyperref (and other packages) don't roll back and so break. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667944/2388. If you really want to continue to use pdfscreen get yourself an historic texlive 2019 (or 2018) and use it, or contact the author and convince him to update the package.